# dropnet api c# unauthorized user exception

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using dropnet api to access dropbox using c#.i send my apikey and secret key,i get token in response.but when i try to get account info or delete a file it throws unauthorized use exceptions.can any one help me.my code is as follow.

```
 DropNet.DropNetClient client = new DropNet.DropNetClient("xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
            DropNet.Models.UserLogin login = client.GetToken();
            client.UserLogin = login;
            string st=client.BuildAuthorizeUrl(client.UserLogin,null);
            client.Delete("/Public/testsk");
            var accountInfo = client.AccountInfo();
```

Regards,

Shah Khalid.

Comment: First, don't post your app key/secret publicly. Second, are you processing the OAuth flow fully, that is, get the request token, build the authorize URL, have the user go there and allow the app, then call for the access token? Presumably the unauthorized error is a 401 meaning you don't have a valid access token: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox API uses standard http error codes,
in your case, 401 usually means that user access token expired or revoked and it should recreated,

All you need to do is re-authenticate end user **dropbox** account by doing next steps in this order:

1. your application basic authentication:

   ```
                       client = new DropNetClient(Settings.Default.DropboxApiKey, Settings.Default.DropboxApiSecret);
                   client.GetToken();
   ```
2. Let user login Dropbox with their account and approve your Dropbox app:

   ```
           string url = Client.BuildAuthorizeUrl();
   ```
3. Retrieve and save authenticated user token:

   ```
           UserLogin accessToken = Client.GetAccessToken();
       Account.Token = accessToken.Token;
       Account.Secret = accessToken.Secret;
       Account.Status = AccountStatus.Active;
   ```

last - save account data in your app - Account.Save()